# Distribution of rounded normally distributed values

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

Suppose I draw some values from $X_i \sim {\mathcal{N}( \mu, \, \sigma^2 )} $ and then round them to the nearest integer. 
Are those rounded values then Binomial distributed?

Comment: no, because binomial distribution is valued on a finite number of integers

Comment: But is it a reasonable approximation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rounding to integers can seriously degrade the data for some purposes, especially if the population variance is small. The effect of rounding on sample means and variances is often minimal, so t methods may not be seriously affected. 
You say
the original data are normal, so you would not likely use rank-based tests, but they *are* seriously affected by rounding because of the potential for creating ties.

Analyses on paired data can be especially sensitive to rounding, even using t methods. 
If differences
are small and have small variances, you can 'round away' a significant difference by rounding to integers (instead of say tenths).
One way to check the damage from rounding is to look at the proportion of ties
in the rounded data.

Only in very unusual circumstances would rounded normal
data be anything like binomial data which take integer values from $0$ up to
some $n.$ (Try to imagine the binomial model, what would be a 'trial', what
would be a 'success'?)

---

Here is a quick experiment. I generate 100 observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=20,\, \sigma=2)$ and round to integers, then check for ties. The original data 
are generated to many decimal places and ties are extremely rare (none in my experiment). But after rounding to integers, there remain only ten uniquely
different values among the 100 observations. However, sample means and SDs
are not much changed by rounding to integers. (See the R output below.) By contrast, rounding to two places leaves 91
uniquely different values (not shown).

```
x = rnorm(100, 20, 2);  length(unique(x))
## 100  # 100 uniquely different observations
rx = round(x);  length(unique(rx))
## 10   # only 10 uniquely different obs after rounding
mean(x); sd(x)
## 19.95831    # sample mean before rounding
## 2.084899    # sample SD before
mean(rx); sd(rx)
## 19.94       # sample Mean after rounding
@@ 2.088061    # sample SD after
```

*Note:* Predicting ties in rounded data is somewhat like the famous birthday
problem, except that different values have different probabilities of producing ties ('matches'). In the case with $\mu = 20$ and $\sigma = 2,$ one might reasonably expect
most values to be in the interval $(14, 26).$ That leaves only 13 integer values to
which one might round.

Comment: Is it mathematically correct to write this "rounded" distribution as:
$ X_i \sim \left \lfloor {\mathcal{N}( \mu, \, \sigma^2 )}  \right \rceil$ ?

Comment: I know of no standard notation for normal data rounded to integers. Yours seems fine, but would have to be explained. Until your method became standard, I would say "$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ rounded to integers."